# jQuery to hide a parent if the child has no text

Tags: jquery

I have this markup:

```
<li class="GRID_ITEM" id="123">
    <img class="imgUrl" src="search_logo_big.png">
    <div class="title"></div>
</li>
```

I'd like to hide `li.GRID_ITEM` if `div.title` has no text.

I don't know how to do this in JQ. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's the `:empty` selector:

```
$('li.GRID_ITEM:has(div.title:empty)').hide();
```

But be warned that `:empty` strictly means no text (including whitespace) and no child elements. If you want to handle cases including whitespace or child elements, then use:

```
$('li.GRID_ITEM').filter(function () {
    return $.trim($(this).find('div.title').text()).length == 0;
}).hide();
```

As Šime Vidas points out, this will also hide any parent that *doesn't have the child element at all*. If that's not what you wanted, you can try this variation which additionally checks if the child element exists:

```
$('li.GRID_ITEM').filter(function () {
    var title = $(this).find('div.title');
    return title.length && $.trim(title.text()).length == 0;
}).hide();
```

Comment: @Box Your second snipped also hides all li.GRID_ITEM elements that don't have a div.title descendant.

Comment: Ah of course, thanks @Šime. Come to think of it though, the OP may or may not want to hide it in that situation.

Comment: @Box No, that's not what I meant. Your original second snippet did hide all li.GRID_ITEM elements that don't have a div.title descendant. `return $.trim($(this).find('div.title').text()).length == 0;` - if the LI does not have a div.title descendant, then text() will return an empty string and the iteration will return true. So that snippet hides all li.GRID_ITEM elements without a div.title descendant which is not what the OP asked for.

Comment: @Šime - that's exactly what I said... and I also provided an alternative following your comment which doesn't do that. The OP also did not mention anything about what to do when the `div.title` descendant doesn't exist.

Comment: @Box Aha, I misread... watching youtube videos with one eye :)

Comment: @Box The return statement is needlessly confusing. Better: `return title.length && $.trim(title.text()).length == 0;`

Comment: @Šime, you're absolutely right. Don't know what I was thinking.